# BigFloat FFT in Julia

Tags: julia, fftw

I'd like to perform FFT over an array of BigFloats in Julia, but so far I couldn't make it possible. I found [FFTW.jl](https://github.com/JuliaMath/FFTW.jl) and followed the instructions in their docs (`importall FFTW`, etc.). Sadly this did not help and I'm still getting `ERROR: type BigFloat not supported` when running a command like `fft([BigFloat(1.0)])`.

Did anybody experience (and hopefully overcome) similar issues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FFTW.jl is a wrapper to the C library [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/) which cannot handle BigFloats. You need to find a pure-Julia code, like [this one in FastTransforms.jl](https://github.com/MikaelSlevinsky/FastTransforms.jl/blob/master/src/fftBigFloat.jl).